# When I "Build for archive" in Xcode 4, where does the file go?

Tags: xcode, ios, xcodebuild

When I "Build for archive" in Xcode 4, where does the file go? As in, where on my computer is the archived app saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It depends on your build location goes (see Xcode > Preferences ... > Locations).

Note that "Build for Archive" doesn't archive your work in the "Archive Location" you enter there ... it just builds it as if it was being archived (so with the same pre/post-scripts being run, the right Configuration, and in your normal building location). To actually archive your work, you need to select plain old "Archive" instead of "Build for Archive".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this preference stored in a plist somewhere? I'm trying to write a script that would need to check for the location.

Comment: @nschum is right, but just be aware of there is no IPA file in archive :)

Comment: You can export archives as IPAs, though: `xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath XXX.xcarchive -exportPath "XXX.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "XXX"` (or through the Xcode Organizer GUI).

Answer (score 5):

For fast direct access to an individual archive, in Xcode's Organizer window, go to the Archives tab, right-click an archive, then "Show in Finder".