# How to make .ipa file in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Since I upgraded xCode to 4.5 I can not find option to save my iOS app as .ipa file which I want to distribute over Testflight. Any suggestions?

Here is screenshot of archive options:

[image: archive options]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Archive you build, then, in the Organizer's `Archives` tab, select the archive you want to export as ipa, click on `Distribute...` and select `Save for Enterprise Ad-Hoc Deployment`.

This is what this looks like on my machine:

[image: Xcode archive export]

Comment: It seems like I dont have this option :/ (I updated my question and added screenshot)

Comment: I don't do Mac development, but the given options you have pretty much look like your Xcode thinks that this is a Mac app! I don't know what triggers this in Xcode but have a look at the build settings of your target: Supported Platform should say 'iOS' and Target Device Family should say 'iPhone', 'iPad', or 'Universal' depending on your app. (See my updated post!)

Comment: This was the problem and here is how to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411105/my-iphone-app-is-being-archived-as-mac-app-archive-and-not-ios-app-archive

Comment: @knagode: Whats the difference between `Archive` & `Build For Archive` ?

Comment: "Build for Archive" doesn't archive your work it just makes a build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444880/when-i-build-for-archive-in-xcode-4-where-does-the-file-go